# Get reference to element of php array searched by key

Tags: php, arrays, search, reference

I have the following php array structure:

```
$r = [
 [
   'id' => 'abc',
   'children' => [
      [
        'id' => 'def',
        'children' => []
      ],
      [
        'id' => 'ghi',
        'children' => [
          [
            'id' => 'jkl',
            'children' => []
          ],
          [
            'id' => 'mno',
            'children' => []
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

and a function to search for a parent like:

```
function &getElementByUuid($element, $uuid){
    foreach($element as $child){
        if($child['id'] == $uuid){
            return $child;
        }
        if(isset($child['children'])){
            if($childFound = $this->getElementByUuid($child['children'], $uuid)){
                return $childFound;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

calling this by

```
getElementByUuid($r, 'ghi');
```

Searching already works perfectly, since it returns the parent of the element, I want to add childs to.

But I need to get the found parent array element as reference so I can add array elements to it.

Like:

```
$parent = getElementByUuid($r, 'ghi');
$parent['children'][] = [
  'id' => 'xyz',
  'children' => []
];
```

But I cannot get the parent element as reference, though I marked the method with & to return the reference, not the value.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to walk array by reference too and add ampersand before calling the function too. Here is small example, how to return by reference: https://3v4l.org/7seON

```
<?php

$ar = [1,2,3,4];

function &refS(&$ar, $v) {
    foreach ($ar as &$i) {
        if ($i === $v) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
}

$x = &refS($ar, 2);
var_dump($x);
$x = 22;
var_dump($ar);
```

Comment: Was just answering my own question, but you're right with syntax passing everything as refence.. just came up with the same thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am just plain stupid...

Call:

```
$parent =& $this->getElementByUuid($tree, $parentId);
```

and method should look like this:

```
function &getElementByUuid(&$element, $uuid){
    foreach($element as &$child){
        if($child['id'] == $uuid){
            return $child;
        }
        if(isset($child['children'])){
            if($childFound =& $this->getElementByUuid($child['children'], $uuid)){
                return $childFound;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Else, php creates copy of the values and iterates through the values, return a reference to the copy, not the reference to the refence.

I hope this might help someone else ;)